# jQuery drag and drop not working when container is overflow div

Tags: jquery

Here is a code snipplet of my issue(s) ([JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y49bg4pf/3/))

```js
$("#container").droppable({
  accept: '.draggable',
  tolerance: 'pointer',
  drop: function(event, ui) {

    var clone = $(ui.helper).clone();
    var parent = $('#container');

    $(this).append(clone);
    var leftAdjust = clone.position().left - parent.position().left;
    var topAdjust = clone.position().top - parent.position().top;
    clone.css({
      left: leftAdjust,
      top: topAdjust
    });
    clone.css('z-index', 1000);
    $(".draggable").draggable();
  }
});

$(".draggable").draggable({
  helper: 'clone',
  cursor: 'hand',
  zindex: 1000
});
```

```css
#container{
  position: relative;
}
.draggable{
  height: 40px;
  width: 80px;
  background-color: maroon;
  color: yellow;
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div class="draggable">some text</div>
<div id="outer" style="padding: 50px;">
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <div id="container" style="height: 400px; overflow: auto !important;">
    <div class="img"><img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/491337595905794049/lWKwJt8Z.jpeg" /></div>
    <br/>
    <div class="img"><img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/491337595905794049/lWKwJt8Z.jpeg" /></div>
    <br/>
    <div class="img"><img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/491337595905794049/lWKwJt8Z.jpeg" /></div>
    <br/>
  </div>
</div>
```

My main issue is when you drag the box on the top left corner into the container it works fine UNTIL you scroll down the container then it goes all haywire and doesn't drop where you actually dropped etc.

Another issue i'm having is once you drag and drop onto the container, when you drag and drop the new item its duplicating itself.

**EDIT FOR CLARIFICATION**

When you move the DIV into the container, it needs to stay where you moved it to inside the container when you scroll.